# How to Include JS file in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Im looking for a way to access a variable from external js file which i included in assets/data folder

below is what i tried

placed **`test.js`** in **assets/data folder**

in **`test.js`** added variable `testvar = "heloo from external js";`

added script tag in `src/index.html` `<script src="assets/data/test.js"></script>`

in `app.component.ts` i added this line after imports;`declare var testvar: any;`

in constructor added this line to log the value `console.log(testvar);`

result is ***error*** : ***ERROR ReferenceError: testvar is not defined***

so, how can i use my js variable in typescript ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**This solution only worked for me**

> Put the import js in `src/index.html` header tag, before the
>   `build/polyfills.js` and `build/main.js` (they are in body tag);

Example  : I created a file `src/assets/test.js` with a `var testvar`, imported in `src/index.html` and then in `src/app/app.component.ts` declared `declare var testvar;`.

**test.js**

```
var testvar = "Hello from external js";
```

**index.html**

```
...
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/test.js"></script> //here, not in body
...
```

**app.componet.ts**

```
declare var testvar;

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  constructor(private statusbar : StatusBar,  splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
   alert(testvar);
...
```

Comment: some suggestions if this doesnt work: Add :any next to "declare var testvar" . Add allowJs:true to your tsconfig.json in the project's directory.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on misha130's answer. You would need to import it into the file you want like this:

```
import * as test from '../assets/data/test'
```

This way you have access to the test variable.

```
console.log(test.testvar);
```

Comment: To make it work, add 
declare var testvar; to app.componet.ts as rashidnk said. Then testvar can be accessed like this: 
console.log(testvar); Notes that doing this way, there is no need to add test.js to index.html

Answer (score 3):

Remove it from index.html and use it like this:

```
import '../assets/data/test';
```

Comment: the error is gone ? but how to access the varibale ?

Comment: console.log(testvar); is undefined

Comment: The test is now the var, not testvar

Comment: your answer is incomplete bro

Comment: I edited the answer and removed the alias so maybe its less confusing now. You can just console log testvar now

Comment: import what? it's empty

Comment: where to add this line?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that works for me on ionic 3.20.0:

1. Create this file src/assets/data/test.js. In this file declare these variables:

   `testvar = "Hello from external js"; // notes: there is no var keywork
   testvar2 = "Hello from external js"; // notes: there is no var keywork
   var testvar3 = "Hello from external js"; // this will not work`
2. In app.component.ts, add these lines to import the javascript file and declare its variables:

   `import * as test from '../assets/data/test'; // check correct path
   declare var testvar: any; // each declaration should be on separate line
   declare var testvar2: any;
   declare var testvar3: any;`
3. Now in app.component.ts, you can access those variables like this:

   `console.log(testvar); // not test.testvar
   console.log(testvar2);
   console.log(testvar3); // will be undefined because of the var keywork`

Final words: there is no need to add a link to test.js in src/index.html if we are doing like above.

Answer (score 1):

None of above solutions worked for me, In first solution js file loads at the time of application loading that's not perfect solution when you have bulk js file.

I was looking for dynamic solution to load the external library and there is library for loading asynchronous JavaScript files. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs

Install the package:

```
npm i scriptjs
```

Then use it anywhere like below:

```
import { get } from 'scriptjs';

ngOnInit() {

    get("assets/js/searchEmp.js", () => {
        getSerchInspContext = this;
        loadSearchEmp();
    });}
```

OR

You can simply use the jquery method to append or remove the script tag in your header.

To add .js file, call below line under ngOnInit():

```
$('head').append('<script async src="assets/js/search.js"></script>');
```

Remove .js file:

```
document.querySelector('script[src="assets/js/search.js"]').remove();
```