# ionic 3 adding js code

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

sorry for my english.
how to add js code in ionic 3 for use in particular page.
im create countdown timer like this but ts (typescript) not accept js code.
Thanks.
like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSa2z.png)

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of Javascript, it does accept Javascript code. 
Can you show us code you're trying to add?

Comment: thanks zooty:  i'm using that js code : https://codepen.io/arcarr/pen/vGVGXN

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom JS in ionic is usually not needed.

But if you want to use use it anyway, You can refer to the [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833895/how-to-include-js-file-in-ionic-3) on using the custom JS to the ionic project.

Comment: im attempting these step nothing happens just pop window generate and say hello from external js.

Comment: var testvar = "Hello from external js" in js file

Comment: add js reference in index.html <script src="assets/js/test.js"></script>

Comment: declare var testvar; in component.ts

Comment: alert(testvar); in component.ts under the constructor {}