# Javascript alert into ionic login page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to simple call a JavaScript alert into the login page of an Ionic app.

However it is not working.

At first, I'm trying to add a simple alert, then I will need to add zeros automaticly to the left on the use login input.

If I can't even use an alert, imagine adding more complex code.

Here is the html I have here.

```
<ion-content padding class="content-bg-color">
 <div class="logo-pagina-login">
  <img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
 </div>
 <p class="acesse-sua-conta" [@acesseSuaContaIn]="estadoAnimacaoAcesseSuaConta">
  Acesse sua conta
 </p>
 <ion-item class="form-input-value" [@texboxIn]="estadoAnimacaoTextBox">
  <ion-label floating class="login-page-form">
      <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
      Usuário
  </ion-label>
 <ion-input type="text" autocapitalize="none" #txtLogin class="login-page-form"(ionBlur)="GetParamsPreAuthentication(txtLogin.value);"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item class="form-input-value" [@texboxIn]="estadoAnimacaoTextBox">
  <ion-label floating class="login-page-form">
      <ion-icon name="unlock"></ion-icon>
      Senha
  </ion-label>
  <ion-input [type]="senhaPasswordType" #txtSenha class="login-page-form"></ion-input>
  <button ion-button icon-only item-end clear default class="loginPasswordIcon" (click)="TogglePasswordSenha()">
    <ion-icon [name]="senhaPasswordIcon"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  </ion-item>
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'hide-element': !habilitaData }">
  <ion-item class="form-input-value" [@texboxIn]="estadoAnimacaoTextBox">
      <ion-label #lbDataNascimento floating class="login-page-form">
          <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
          {{lbDataNascimento.label}}{{textoCampoData}}
      </ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" #txtData cancelText="Cancelar" doneText="Selecionar">     </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  </div>
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'hide-element': !habilitaPergunta }">
  <ion-item class="form-input-value" [@texboxIn]="estadoAnimacaoTextBox">
      <ion-label floating class="login-page-form">
          <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon>
          Resposta
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input [type]="respostaPasswordType" #txtResposta class="login-page-form"></ion-input>
      <button ion-button icon-only item-end clear default class="loginPasswordIcon" (click)="TogglePasswordResposta()">
        <ion-icon [name]="respostaPasswordIcon"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-label #lbPerguntaChave class="login-page-form label-pergunta-chave">{{lbPerguntaChave.value}}{{preAuthentication.PerguntaChave}}</ion-label>
  </div>
  <button ion-button block color="secondary" class="btn-entrar" (click)="OnEntrarClick(txtLogin.value, txtSenha.value, habilitaPergunta ? txtResposta.value : '', habilitaData ? txtData : '');" [@buttonIn]="estadoAnimacaoBotao">Entrar</button>
 <p class="esqueceu-a-senha" [@esqueciMinhaSenhaIn]="estadoAnimacaoEsqueciMinhaSenha">
  Esqueceu a senha? <a (click)="OnEsqueciASenhaClick();">Clique aqui</a>
 </p>

 </ion-content>
```

I´ve tried to adding the alert in this page, but the app won't recognize. And I'm not sure why. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering your question, I would like to suggest you to use **AlertController** provided by Ionic to display alerts. You can even add checkboxes, buttons and other supported elements inside the ionic alert
Reference & Example code: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert

You also have the option to use **ModalController** for fully customised alert/prompt boxes 
Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

Now, to answer your question: **If you want to use custom javascript inside your ionic project, you should include it in index.html** file generated by the ionic framework.
To understand how to add custom javascript in ionic, checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134679/9088454